# Error Invalid JSON response - DataTables Plugin

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, datatables

Estoy trayendo mis datos de la base de datos **MySQL** en formato JSON usando el plugin de DataTables, pero en el depurador de Chrome no me muestra los datos solo la consulta de filas que hago, creo que no estoy accediendo bien al formato JSON que estoy trayendo, mi código es el siguiente:

```html
$number_filter_row = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connect, $query));

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query . $query1);

$data = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $sub_array = array();
 $sub_array[] = $row["keyordint"];
 $sub_array[] = $row["trabajo"];
 $sub_array[] = $row["f_ingreso"];
 $sub_array[] = $row["f_solicita"];
 $sub_array[] = $row["f_aprueba"];
 $data[] = $sub_array;
}

function get_all_data($connect)
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM ordint";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
 return mysqli_num_rows($result);
}

$output = array(
 "draw"    => intval($_POST["draw"]),
 "recordsTotal"  =>  get_all_data($connect),
 "recordsFiltered" => $number_filter_row,
 "data"    => $data
);

echo json_encode($output);
```

Este es mi Ajax que hago:

```html
 function fetch_data(is_date_search, start_date='', end_date='')
 {
  var dataTable = $('#order_data').DataTable({
   "processing" : true,
   "serverSide" : true,
   "order" : [],
   "ajax" : {
    url:"fettwo.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:{
     is_date_search:is_date_search, start_date:start_date, end_date:end_date
    }
   }
  });
 }
```

Y este es el array que me devuelve pero sin datos solo las filas que existen en la tabla:

```html
{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":17300,"recordsFiltered":null,"data":[]}
```

Este es el formato de la base de datos que no me funciona

[image: Este es el formato de la base de datos que no me funciona]

Este es el formato que tiene la base de datos que si funciona

[image: Este es el formato que tiene la base de datos que si funciona]

No se si hay problema con que este con una como categoria **Tablas**

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar asignando en una variable la conversión, ejm:

```
var unavariable = JSON.parse(respuesta).elÍndicequeNecesitas;
```

o desde la vista, en dos etiquieras PHP:

```
$unavariable = json_decode(respuesta, true);
```

Y accedes a la posición que necesites así: $unavariable["laPosicion"]